# How do people know which byte to use for certain task - python sockets

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, byte

```
tosSocket = socket.socket()
tosSocket.connect(("live4.somegame.com", 3600))


msgByte = chr(30) + chr(1) + chr(0)

tosSocket.send(msgByte.encode())
```

So for some simple online game that runs on flash or unity some people make bots for it via sockets. By simple I mean its just clicking based i.e.. click join game. "msgByte = chr(30) + chr(1) + chr(0)" this byte if you send it the bot clicks joins the game on the live server. This is based on a real game  website that someone made a bot for that  I found online.  I'm wondering how do they find the bytes for these specific task? Is there like some tool that they're using so that they replicate the task by themselves and it shows what byte was used? That would be useful if anyone knows of one

Comment: "*I'm wondering how do they find the bytes for these specific task?*" - they either 1) found documentation for it, 2) found a pre-existing code implementation, or 3) reverse engineered it by looking at which bytes each task actually sends. "*Is there like some tool that they're using so that they replicate the task by themselves and it shows what byte was used?*" - maybe. Tools like Wireshark do exist, with plenty of dissectors built-in for more popular protocols, or readily available for install for less common ones

Comment: Wireshark was exactly what I needed! Thanks.